# Non-Funded PhD in Education the US

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, funding, international-students

I have been accepted to a US university for a PhD in Education. The problem is that I’m not given any funding packages. I reached out to my professor and program director, and I was told to check for assistantships. I’m not sure if they become available though.

As an international student, I was wondering if there are other options for me to seek funding that can fully support my tuition and living expenses?

Comment: Have you looked for any fellowship from your home country ? Education is the foundation of a country. There may be some fellowship available.

Comment: Yes, but I am from Iran and we don't have fellowships for studying in the US.

Comment: You solved a puzzle for me. In the 1970's, there were a lot of Iranian students in the US universities. A few decades later, almost of all of them seem to disappear.

Comment: In the university that I am accepted, there are almost 300 other Iranian students.

Comment: @Parmis since there are already 300 iranian students, get in touch with them or their association (for sure there is one, a quick google gives you plenty of results for many US universities, see for example Purdue https://web.ics.purdue.edu/~icc/ , Urbana (IL) https://www.icauiuc.org/ , Boulder https://mines.campuslabs.com/engage/organization/iranian-student-association ... )
Don't be too depressed to discover that a relevant % of them is from wealth family that can support them through their PhD studies ...

Comment: @Nobody the students until the 70s were the lucky consequence of the unlucky plan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Iranian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat

Comment: In some cases, it makes sense for you to apply for a Teaching Assistant position at another department (for instance, Math Department if your subspecialty is Math Education). But, in general, it will be tough since your visa will not allow you to work outside of the university.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, fortunately, I found a TA position, and among all the applicants I was selected. All I need to do is get my visa.

Comment: Thanks, I succeeded, fortunately. @EarlGrey

Answer (score 3):

This is not helpful to you, but as a point of reference: In the United States, graduate students are generally not supported by the university unless (i) they are hired by a specific investigator who has external research funding, or (ii) the department has a teaching mission that requires a lot of Teaching Assistants (TAs). The former is often the case in engineering and science departments, the latter in mathematics and some liberal arts departments. Education departments do not fall in these categories, and most of their students are self-supported -- they have to find work on their own if they need the money.

Sometimes, the department is in need of people teaching a course or two here or there, and that would provide some funding. It is something you can ask the department into whose program you've been admitted. But it is not commonly the case that all (or even many) students in Education are fully supported.

Comment: Your phrasing of 'almost all graduate students are no supported' threw me off at first as the two exceptions you mention do cover a large proportion of all graduate students. It is true however, that most of those not covered by these two cases are unsupported.

Comment: @quarague I don't have statistics about how many students are in which field, so I've just removed the "almost all" quantifier.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you, I found a TA position, and I was accepted. All I have to do is get my visa. All it took was too much research to find a relevant TA position. Since I have a strong resume, I could get the position.